# How to turn off Vibration (in all apps) via ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I'm creating tests with `UiAutomator` and Vibration is used in app, but don't need it in tests.

I'm doing so:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("adb shell cmd appops set <app package name> VIBRATE ignore")
```

but this command is not working for me, maybe its because vibration goes from notification.

Comment: is the answer below helping to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to remove `adb shell` from the string provided to `executeShellCommand` method. The working statement will be:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("cmd appops set <app package name> VIBRATE ignore")
```